# SSLHandshakeException while using AWS SDK for Java API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, java, aws-sdk

I'm using the Java API to upload and download files in Amazon S3. It was working perfectly until about a week ago, and it just stopped working altogether even though I hadn't touched the code. I'm wondering if there's a solution to this. Thanks!

Over here's the code that was worked fine:

```
AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESSKEYID, SECRETKEY);
AmazonS3Client s3client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
List<String> bucketList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Bucket bucket : s3client.listBuckets()) {
        System.out.println(bucket.getName());
    }
```

And here's the error:

```
Apr 11, 2015 9:44:12 PM com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient executeHelper
INFO: Unable to execute HTTP request: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1904)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:279)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:273)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1446)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:901)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:837)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1023)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:534)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:402)
at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:118)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:178)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:685)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:460)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:295)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3736)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3686)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listBuckets(AmazonS3Client.java:688)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listBuckets(AmazonS3Client.java:696)
at keymanager.service.AWSAPI.getBucketList(AWSAPI.java:130)
at keymanager.view.KeyManager.initializeBucketList(KeyManager.java:59)
at keymanager.view.KeyManager.connectButtonActionPerformed(KeyManager.java:626)
at keymanager.view.KeyManager.access$1000(KeyManager.java:22)
at keymanager.view.KeyManager$12.actionPerformed(KeyManager.java:425)
```

I'd done a bit of research, and some had suggested that the problem could be with the permissions. However, I think I've followed the instructions here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/GettingStartedGuide/tke_setup_creds.html#d0e387 as well as I could. I'm really pretty stuck, guys. Thanks, and any help at all will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem. The solution turned out to be the device wrong date. Try to keep your device date updated. The reason is that SSL certificates have issuance/expiry date that are being verified against your device date.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered similar problem. My issue was I have marked the proxy configuration in the beans xml file as given below.

`<bean id="clientConfiguration" class="com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration">
  <property name="proxyHost" value="proxy.server.com"/>
   <property name="proxyPort" value="8080"/>
</bean>`

But forgot to set the property .

Once entered the protocol it started working